# Restrição de Acesso com ASP Clássico

Tags: asp

estou colocar uma cláusula de restrição de acesso.

Eu criei uma tabela com as pessoas que podem acessar, meu intuito é que as que podem acessar sejam direcionadas para a página e as que não podem sejam direcionadas para outra

Mas tem algo errado

```
usuario = right(Request.servervariables("LOGON_USER"),7)

set RSUSER = conexao.execute("SELECT usuario FROM tabela ")


if usuario = RSUSER("usuario") 
    then response.redirect("../index.asp")
    else 
    response.redirect("acesso_restrito.asp")
}
```

Comment: Creio que falta uma cláusula WHERE: `"SELECT usuario FROM tabela WHERE usuario = '"& usuario &"'"`

Comment: Eu acho que não é isso, pois eu não vou exibir dados de usuários especificos. Eu quero ver se o usuário consta na tabela e se constar ele pode ir para uma determinada página.

Comment: Sem usar WHERE vc irá selecionar a tabela toda.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você deva verificar se o usuário está contido na tabela ou não, ao invés de só consistir isso com o retorno da query. Estou considerando que existe um campo LOGIN na tabela. Caso seja outro campo, só usar o no WHERE. Exemplo:

```
usuario = right(Request.servervariables("LOGON_USER"),7)
set RSUSER = conexao.execute("SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM tabela WHERE login = " & usuario )
'aqui verifico se contém retorno. Se sim, significa que o usuário está na tabela em quetão.
if not RSUSER.EOF then 
    response.redirect("../index.asp")
else 
    response.redirect("acesso_restrito.asp")
end if

conexao.close()
```

Comment: então... não tem login, é o próprio login do windows que estiver aberto no computador, mas a pessoa não passa por um formulário para logar

Comment: Sem problema. Mas você vai bater a sua variável "usuario" com alguma informação na tabela "tabela". Certo? Fazendo conforme eu descrevi, vai funcionar. No seu IF você havia consistido "usuario = RSUSER("usuario")". Significa que o campo "usuario" da sua tabela contém a possível informação retornada na sua variável usuario. Certo?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui! 
Na verdade,só estava faltando um loop para percorrer os registros da tabela inteira.

Comment: Edite sua resposta e coloque o código completo da sua solução que funcionou. Isso ajudará demais usuários que possam ter a mesma dúvida que a sua.